# aligning an absolute div to the center

Tags: html, css

What I did was to use `margin:20%` on the main `div`... But I don't think it is the best way:

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    background-color:#F0C;
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;

    margin-left:20%;
    alignment-adjust:central;
    position:absolute;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color:#3F6;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:30%;
}

.leftSidebar {
    background-color:#C63;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin-left:-80%;
}

.rightsidebar {
    background-color:#66F;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="maincontent">
        <!-- main content goes here -->
    </div>

    <div class="leftSidebar">
        <!-- left sidebar content goes here -->
    </div>

    <div class="rightsidebar">
        <!-- right sidebar content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I position the `.wrapper` to the center? Is there an easy way?

Also, what is the difference between using the `left`/`right` properties and `margin-left`/`margin-right`?

Comment: is there a reason why you are using absolute positioning? i never use that for layout purposes..

Comment: whats the difference between absolute and fixed position,,and the default position

Comment: default is `static`, which means it behaves like a normal block or inline element. `fixed` means it is taken out of the layout flow, and will remain at exactly the same position in the browser window, even if the page is scrolled.  `absolute` means it it is taken out of the layout flow, and put on a different layer - so it can be freely positioned with left/right/top/bottom, an so it can be stacked on top of other elements.

Comment: whats wrong with absolute position then?!? what is the difference between margin-left and left?!?

Comment: absolute positioning is harder to handle, especially if your layout gets more complex. i use it only if i need to stack elements on top of each other. see my answer for a more standard approach to center your content.

Comment: margin-left and left can produce the same result, but are not the same. margin-left adds a margin to the left, left shifts the element to the right (and can be only used on element with absolute, relative, or fixed positioning).

Comment: thanks for the answer. so should I use margin-left/right instead of an absolute position?!?

Comment: how do you position it without an absolute postion?

Comment: it all depends on what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I think i got it.. i could do this: margin-left:20%;
 margin-right:20%; and it will center my content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. I will try to do it with percents instead..why do I need the 50% left?!?

Comment: You're putting it at 50% from the left of the page then moving it back half of its width. It's a common method.

Comment: I used this: margin-left:-500px; .. instead of left:-500px..why did it work?!? whats the difference between left and margin-left

Comment: I am using the same approach with position: absolute. You can do the same to achieve the same result vertically like so - top: 50%; margin-top: -(half the size)px;

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: When using `position:absolute;`, `left` dictates the element's position relative to the entire document. `margin-left` dictates its position relative to where it is.

Comment: I did this: margin-left:20%;  it seems near the center.. I erased teh absolute position.. seems to be in teh center..but I feel it isnt the right technique that will guarantee my text to be in the center all the time

Comment: ...Then use my method. That's why I answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be: skip the absolute positioning, and use `margin:0 auto;` to center your content (no margin on top and bottom, and automatic margin left and right).

```
.wrapper
{
    background-color:#F0C;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: wow..if hte margin is auto..then the div is set to the center.. but what if i do want to use top and bottom elements..to bring the div downwards/upwards?!?

Comment: how do you position it without an absolute postion?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: there is no to way vertically center a `div` without positioning it absolutely. The `margin: auto` technique only works horizontally.

Comment: If you just want to push it down, you can use the following: margin: 20px auto 0 auto; (adjust the 20px for more or less padding on the top). If you want it centered vertically, then you'll have to use percent-based positioning.